# Xamarin Forms: custom progressbar renderer for UWP and win8.1

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

Hi I am developing an app in XAMARIN FORMS using PCL project. In that I am using progressbar. I need to change the color of filled area. For that I tried color property but it shows no color property found for progressbar. So for that I created an custom renderer for progressbar so that I can set its color but I am not able to find any property to change its color in UWP.
Can anyone suggest me a way to change the filled area color for all platforms specially for UWP and windows 8.1.

[For android and ios I have used this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28894/progressbar-color-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: no code example ? this question could be be a lot more specific....

Comment: @AnthonyLambert I have shared the code reference for android and ios, and I am trying to figure out it for uwp  and win8.1

Answer (score 1):

Update: Did you try to create custom Renderer for UWP and change Foreground color?

```
var pb = Element as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ProgressBar();
pb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
```

Also for UWP you can override default style for ProgressBar.
Just grab default style from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299145.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and replace Foreground value, for example:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
```

Than put this style in App.xaml inside UWP specific project

```
<Application
    x:Class="Xamarin.Prism.UWP.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>

        <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ProgressBar -->
        PUT YOUR MODIFIED STYLE HERE

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Now all ProgressBar controls will use your custom color

Comment: Is there any similar way like UWP that I can use for that I can specify color code from my xaml page and it will affect all the remaining platforms

Comment: I just started with Xamarin so still don't know.

Comment: how can I set SolidColorBrush by string

Comment: [Check my helper](https://gist.github.com/matrostik/ba5836ac4465b65a8ed847bc77c92d61)